# int.to_bytes equivalent for Decimals

Tags: python, encoding, byte, decimal

I need to use the `int.to_bytes` method but I get the following error `OverflowError: int too big to convert`.
Therefore I was told to use the `Decimal` class that is slower but works with bigger numbers, except I cannot find the exact equivalent to the `int.to_bytes` function.

Here's an example of code with smaller numbers that works with `to_bytes` but doesn't with an other method :

```
from decimal import *

message = b"Message"
length = len("Message")

number = int.from_bytes(message, 'little')
print(number) # 28542640894207309

message2 = int.to_bytes(number,length,'little')
print(message2) # b'Message'

message3 = str(Decimal(number)).encode()
print(message3) # b'28542640894207309'
```

I'd like my 3rd print to be the same as the 2nd

The code that throws the error is

```
from sympy import randprime
from decimal import *

p, q = [randprime(0, 1 << 1024)] * 2
n = p * q

length = len("Message")
message = b"Message"

e = 0x10001
m = int.from_bytes(message, 'little')
print(m)

c = pow(m, e, n)
phi = int(pow(p-1,2))
d = pow(e, -1, phi)
m2 = pow(c,d,n)

message2 = int.to_bytes(m2,length,'little') # Error happens here
print(message2)
```

Python version is 3.11.7

Comment: Can you show the code that triggers the OverflowError? Maybe it can be fixed

Comment: What is your question?  Are you trying to call `number.to_bytes(...)`?

Comment: @FrankYellin Almost. I need an other function that does the exact same as `number.to_bytes(...)` but works with bigger numbers, like with the Decimal class

Comment: @KellyBundy, I'm sorry, [it's my first day here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpMLIUzE9h8)

Comment: @user2722968 Amazing how well that fits, even the "10 years" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
byte_length = (number.bit_length() + 7) // 8
number.to_bytes(byte_length, 'little')
```

Comment: It's odd that `to_bytes` can't calculate the size for you automatically.

Comment: Most of the uses for this function are cryptography.  You already know how many bytes the "key" is supposed to be.  And if, by small chance, the integer is too small, you want it padded out with null bytes.